# Relation of luminance in RGB/XYZ color and physical luminance

Tags: graphics, colors, physics

Short version: When a color described in XYZ or xyY coordinates has a luminance Y=1, what are the physical units of that? Does that mean 1 candela, or 1 lumen? Is there any way to translate between this conceptual space and physical brightness?

Long version: I want to simulate how the sky looks in different directions, at different times of day, and (eventually) under different cloudiness and air pollution conditions. I've learned enough to figure out how to translate a given spectrum into a *chrominance*, for example xyz coordinates. But almost everything I've read on color theory in graphical display is focused on relative color, so the luminance is always 1. Non-programming color theory describes the units of luminance, so that I can translate from a spectrum in watts/square meter/steradian to candela or lumens, but nothing that describes the units of luminance in programming. What are the units of luminance in XYZ coordinates? I understand that the actual brightness of a patch would depend on monitor settings, but I'm really not finding any hints as to how to proceed.

Below is an example of what I'm coming across. The base color, at relative luminance of 1, was calculated from first principles. All the other colors are generated by increasing or decreasing the luminance. Most of them are plausible colors for mid-day sky. For the parameters I've chosen, I *believe* the total intensity in the visible range is 6.5 W/m2/sr = 4434 cd/m2, which seems to be in the right ballpark according to [Wiki: Orders of Magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(luminance)). Which color would I choose to represent that patch of sky?

[image: Chrominance-Luminance]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more, luminance is usually expressed in candelas per square meter (cd/m<sup>2</sup>), and CIE XYZ's Y component is a luminance in cd/m<sup>2</sup> — if the convention used is "[absolute XYZ](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1202772/Color-Topics-for-Programmers#CIE_XYZ)", which is rare. (The link is to an article I wrote which contains more detailed information.) More commonly, XYZ colors are normalized such that the white point (such as the D65 or D50 white point) has Y = 1 (or Y = 100).